# Software to simulate how an economy would have behaved had a policy not been implemented?

Tags: simulations

For my econ class, I chose to write a paper on how GST affected india's economy, though my teacher has approved it, I would like to add data showing how India's economy would have behaved without GST, however being in 12 th I have no idea how to do this. Are there any free apps that can help me with this?

Comment: Have a look at GTAP in GAMS, it is used for CGE modeling and looking at alternative scenarios, such as by chnging tax rates etc afaik but I am nt sure if something as complex and major as the Indian GST can be implemented here, or if the data even is available

Comment: @IshanKashyapHazarika GAMS is not free

Comment: Oh sorry, didnt know. I had access to it through an organisation I was working for so I wasnt sure

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To simulate a whole economy you will need something like:

- octave
- Python
- Julia
- Fortran

All of the software above is free.

Comment: So I basically have to write  a program,  right? No ready made app exits(where I can just input parametersm am I right?

Comment: Thanks  for the help!

Comment: @fhhh to my best knowledge there isn’t any app where you could simulate a whole economy just by entering parameters, so yea you have to write the code for simulation yourself

Comment: oh,  I  see. Thank you.